# Modernize I5/As400 program with Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I have been given the task of modernizing my company's I5 based point of sale system. The main push is to create a friendlier interface/better data views without losing business logic.

Is there a good Java way of interacting with an interactive (non-command line) I5 program? Something alone the lines of what PHP provides with their 5250 Bridge? I'm considering using he 5250 bridge, but I'd prefer a Java base solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the interactive part of the application is separable ... Why not use the Toolbox for Java to call the underlying programs directly and create a remote GUI? You can call APIs, PGMs, and CL commands remotely from Java.

Comment: Agreed.  Trying to fit a GUI interface into a 5250 design is, to me, a square peg/round hole scenario.  This is especially true with subfile screens or when you need more than one screen for input because of 5250 screen size restrictions.  Design a GUI user interface as a GUI user interface instead of a screen-scraper.  Just my opinion, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The [IBM Developer Kit for Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/calrpgex.htm) allows you to run Java code on the iSeries.

You can call Java code directly from RPG/COBOL programs using the JNI interface.  [Here's an article describing how to call Java from an RPG program.](http://www.itjungle.com/mpo/mpo013102-story02.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the ProgramCall class in the IBM Java Toolbox.  This will allow you to call any given program but you need some elbow grease to get the parameters right etc.  Here it is a benefit to get the I5 compilers to create PCML files which can be used to create the ProgramCall arguments automatically.  We have 1ms tourn around time for such a call from a PC.

Note:  QTEMP is not available unless you do serious voodoo.